# concurrently iterating through even and odd items of list

Tags: python, for-loop, python-itertools

I have a list of items (which are HTML table rows, extracted with Beautiful Soup) and I need to iterate over the list and get even and odd elements (I mean index) for each loop run. 
My code looks like this:

```
for top, bottom in izip(table[::2], table[1::2]):
    #do something with top
    #do something else with bottom
```

How to make this code less ugly? Or maybe is it good way to do this?

EDIT:

```
table[1::2], table[::2]  => table[::2], table[1::2]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
def alternate(i):
    i = iter(i)
    while True:
        yield(i.next(), i.next())

>>> list(alternate(range(10)))
[(0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5), (6, 7), (8, 9)]
```

This solution works on any sequence, not just lists, and doesn't copy the sequence (it will be far more efficient if you only want the first few elements of a long sequence).

Answer (score 5):

`izip` is a pretty good option, but here's a few alternatives since you're unhappy with it:

```
>>> def chunker(seq, size):
...     return (tuple(seq[pos:pos+size]) for pos in xrange(0, len(seq), size))
...
>>> x = range(11)
>>> x
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> chunker(x, 2)
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x00B44328>
>>> list(chunker(x, 2))
[(0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5), (6, 7), (8, 9), (10,)]
>>> list(izip(x[1::2], x[::2]))
[(1, 0), (3, 2), (5, 4), (7, 6), (9, 8)]
```

As you can see, this has the advantage of properly handling an uneven amount of elements, which may or not be important to you. There's also this recipe from the [itertools documentation itself](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes):

```
>>> def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
...     "grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG', 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
...     args = [iter(iterable)] * n
...     return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)
...
>>>
>>> from itertools import izip_longest
>>> list(grouper(2, x))
[(0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5), (6, 7), (8, 9), (10, None)]
```

Comment: Thanks - both recipes looks good. Anyway I asked because I was interested what are the other ways to do this (and to learn more Python -- and I did :))

Answer (score 0):

Looks good. My only suggestion would be to wrap this in a function or method. That way, you can give it a name (`evenOddIter()`) which makes it much more readable.

Comment: What is the difference between function and method in this context?

Comment: It depends on whether the code above is part of a class or top level. If it's in a class which gets a lot of reuse, it might make sense to use a method. When using a function, then it would be more simple to reuse outside any class but it would clutter the global namespace.

Comment: it's in a class, but this loop is executed only in one place so I think there's need to make a method from this. thanks anyway